# Is there a free option for playing WMA files?

Tags: wma

Any free codecs out there to get my WMA files playing on Rhythmbox? (11.04)

Answer (score 10):

Another good thing is to install the package [ubuntu-restricted-extras](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-restricted-extras)

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

It will install a lot more than just codecs for wma files. But you shouldn't have any problems with media files after the installation.

Answer (score 2):

Fairly sure it's in one of the 'restricted' packages.  Try adding:

- gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly-multiverse
- gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly

One of those should handle WMA, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

You can use VLC media player. It's an open source project, plus it has loads of features.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "free"? open-source? or simply usable without paying anything? I doubt there are open-source codecs for wma, but I think you can install them as part of ubuntu-restricted-extras. At least after installing vlc and all it's dependencies banshee can play wma files.

Comment: Free as in monetarily. I think I've tried the restricted codecs before but I'll try again with this fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

Running 10.04.3, i386 version on AMD Phenom.

Installed the following packages: ubuntu-restricted-extras, gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly, gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly-multiverse, vlc.

DRM-free wma lossless files still won't play in either Banshee or VLC :-/

Comment: Note: lossy wma files play fine in Banshee.

Comment: wmal (lossless), can be decoded with mplayer/mplayer frontends; some xine based players & to some extent with a self built vlc. Note that this is only with w32codecs installed & 32 bit players.  FFmpeg has recently added wmal decoding support but it's currently broken

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is for 18.04.

[Rhythmbox uses gstreamer](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Rhythmbox/FAQ) to play music. The ASF demuxer is provided by the [gstreamer "ugly" plugins](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/asf/index.html?gi-language=c).

**First, run the following commands to enable the** [universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58364/whats-the-difference-between-multiverse-universe-restricted-and-main):

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

**Next, run the following commands to install the ASF demuxer**:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly
```

It's also probably a good idea to install the [restricted extras](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats) package to cover other formats:

```
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```