# What's the difference between multiverse, universe, restricted and main?

Tags: official-repositories

I've been peeking into the ubuntu respository and I see four folders, multiverse, universe, restricted and main.  What do they represent?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

From the [Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu):

> The repository components are:
>
> - **Main** - Officially supported software.
> - **Restricted** - Supported software that is not available under a completely free license.
> - **Universe** - Community maintained software, i.e. not officially supported software.
> - **Multiverse** - Software that is not free.

For example:

- The Ubuntu Desktop team manages the `gnome-terminal` package, it is officially supported and in the `main` repository.
- `bcmwl-kernel-source` (the Broadcom wireless driver) is in `restricted`, since it is a supported, but proprietary, driver.
- Community written software that is not officially supported (for example, the game `supertuxkart`) is in the `universe` repository.
- Packages like `ubuntu-restricted-extras` (which contains proprietary codecs that allow you to play media files, including flash player) are in the `multiverse` repository because they are not free and their restrictive licenses prevent inclusion in the default package set.

---

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29#Package_classification_and_support):-

[image: classification]

Comment: Additonally: packages in Main and Restricted (almost always) have their translations delivered in ubuntu language packs, whereas packages in Universe and Multiverse deliver their own translations

Comment: In this case the post author uses "free software" to mean FOSS and "non-free software" to mean proprietary and/or paid software.

Comment: What if I am hosting my own apt server, do these even make sense?

Answer (score 16):

Ubuntu provides four different *official software repositories*:

- Main
- Restricted
- Universe
- Multiverse

**Main – Officially Supported, Open-Source Software**:

Licence: Open Source
Updates: Canonical provides critical updates.

**Restricted – Officially Supported, Closed-Source Software**:

Licence: Proprietary
Updates: Canonical provides critical updates supplied by the developers.

**Universe – Community-Maintained, Open-Source Software**:

Licence: Open source
Updates: Canonical does not provide update.
Some updates may be provided by the Ubuntu community.

**Multiverse – Unsupported, Closed-Source and Patent-Encumbered Software**:

Licence: Unknown
Updates: Canonical does not provide updates.
Some updates may be provided by Ubuntu community.

About [Canonical and Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/canonical-and-ubuntu)

<sub>reference [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/194247/whats-the-difference-between-main-restricted-universe-and-multiverse-on-ubuntu/)</sub>

Comment: I wouldn't say that all four are "official". Universe and Multiverse are not official in the meaning that Canonical does invest much of its own resources into it. The unpayed community does the work here for Canonical.