# LuckyBackup for Kubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, backup, nas

I am new to Linux and therefore Kubuntu 14.04.
I loaded 14.04 successfully and now want to use it to back up files from a Linux based (DLINK) NAS drive. This would be a remote drive to the new Kubuntu server. Can I download and install LuckyBackup 0.4.8 to my new server? Where from?

Answer (score 1):

Most if not all useful and stable Open Source software for Ubuntu is available through our well maintained distribution's software repositories.

- [How do I install applications in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu)
- [What's the difference between multiverse, universe, restricted and main?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58364/whats-the-difference-between-multiverse-universe-restricted-and-main)

This means that other than from Windows all software is already included when installing Ubuntu. Less often used applications will however be downloaded to be able to use them.

The easiest way to do so is the **Ubuntu Software Center** which allows to search for applications and then download and install them. Applications listed there generally are tested and stable.

This is also the case for [LuckyBackup](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/luckybackup) [image: Install luckybackup], the graphical frontend for the powerful command line tool rsync.

[image: Install via the software center]

You may also be interested in other backup solutions:

- [Comparison of backup tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools)