# How to Install boost on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, c++, boost

How to download `boost`  in Ubuntu?

Comment: Also see: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&section=all&arch=any&keywords=boost+c%2B%2B&searchon=all

Comment: @muru I edited my question,you may feel no change,but will you provide simple steps to follow?

Answer (score 9):

A quick search of [the packages index](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&arch=any&searchon=all&keywords=boost%20c%2B%2B) shows that [`libboost-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libboost-dev) depends on the default version of the Boost libraries. So:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-dev
```

Comment: what is difference between universe and default ?

Comment: @Ravan http://askubuntu.com/q/58364/158442

Comment: Said it installed it but can't find the libraries anywhere. Where exactly does it think it installed it?

Comment: This installs v1.54 :(