# LibQt4-core has unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dependencies, qt

I'm trying to install libqt4-core, but it seems that for the dependencies, I have more recent versions than are compatible with this package. When I use `sudo apt-get install libqt4-core` my output is as follows:

```
user@computer:~/torch$ sudo apt-get install libqt4-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libqt4-core : Depends: libqt4-dbus (= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
               Depends: libqt4-network (= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
               Depends: libqt4-script (= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
               Depends: libqt4-test (= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
               Depends: libqt4-xml (= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
               Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried doing `sudo apt-get install libqt4-core=4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1` instead in the hopes that this would be compatible with the packages I have installed already, but apt said it didn't find this version.

I also tried uninstalling the dependencies and re-installing them with the older versions, but the dependencies in turn have more dependencies which conflict because they have the newer version number too. I don't think following this all the way down is a good idea, so I stopped. If there was an option to force everything to downgrade to debian version 2ubuntu4 instead of 2ubuntu4.1 that seems like that should fix this.

How can I get this installed?

(cross-post from SO since I realized this is a better place to post this question)

**Edit:**

Output of `uname -a ; lsb_release -rc ; apt-cache showpkg libqt4-core` included as information now:

```
Linux user-asus 3.13.0-68-generic #111-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 18:17:06 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

Package: libqt4-core
Versions: 
4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_universe_binary-amd64_Packages)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_universe_binary-amd64_Packages
                  MD5: f8482ce645d26d9ce978ee864c190ae7
 Description Language: en
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_universe_i18n_Translation-en
                  MD5: f8482ce645d26d9ce978ee864c190ae7


Reverse Depends: 
  debathena-thirdparty-libraries,libqt4-core
  debathena-thirdparty,libqt4-core
  libqt4-core:i386,libqt4-core
  chessx,libqt4-core
Dependencies: 
4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 - libqt4-dbus (5 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4) libqt4-network (5 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4) libqt4-script (5 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4) libqt4-test (5 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4) libqt4-xml (5 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4) libqtcore4 (5 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4) libqt4-core:i386 (0 (null)) 
Provides: 
4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 - 
Reverse Provides:
```

**Edit2:**

More additional information

`sudo aptitude install libqtcore4 libqt4-xml libqt4-test libqt4-script libqt4-network libqt4-dbus`

```
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

`sudo aptitude install libqt4-core`

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libqt4-core{b} 
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
Need to get 6,354 B of archives. After unpacking 133 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libqt4-core : Depends: libqt4-dbus (= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is installed.
               Depends: libqt4-network (= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is installed.
               Depends: libqt4-script (= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is installed.
               Depends: libqt4-test (= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is installed.
               Depends: libqt4-xml (= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is installed.
               Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     libqt4-core [Not Installed]                        

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] q
Abandoning all efforts to resolve these dependencies.
Abort.
```

**Edit3:**

Output of [`apt-cache policy libqt4-core libqtcore4 libqt4-xml libqt4-test libqt4-script libqt4-network libqt4-dbus`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/13477251/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to Settings → Softwares & Updates
2. On Ubuntu Software tab: Enable `universe` component
3. On Updates tab: Enable `trusty-security` & `trusty-updates`
4. Close & Reload
5. `sudo apt-get install libqt4-core`

As you can see here from `apt-cache policy` output:

> ```
> libqt4-core:
>   Installed: (none)
>   Candidate: 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4
>   Version table:
>      4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 0
>         500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
> libqtcore4:
>   Installed: 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1
>   Candidate: 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1
>   Version table:
>  *** 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 0
>         500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
>         500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
>         100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
>      4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 0
>         500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
> ```

- This should be reported as a bug. libqt4-core is uploaded as `universe`, but all its dependences as `main`. All these packages are from same source packages, they should be uploaded under same component. See http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/trusty/qt4-x11
- You have `trusty-updates` enabled for `main` but not for `universe`.

All dependencies are installed with version `4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1` from `trusty-update/main`. And the corresponding libqt4-core with same version is in `trusty-update/universe`.

You may try disable `universe`, `trusty-security` & `trusty-updates` close the window without reloading then open it again and enable them. Or enable them manually by editing `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: You should explain that. Most likely `trusty-updates` isn't enabled for `universe` =)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've already done these - (I have main, universe, restricted, and multiverse enabled and trusty-security and trusty-updates installed for updates).

Comment: @A.B. Thank you for pushing me to do that, sometimes I feel lazy. Thank you for raisig that question for easy/clean cmdline manipulation of sources. Legacy may be the best uploading `/etc/apt/sources.list`, edit, put it back. :D

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer! I just did your new suggestion of disabling `universe`, `trusty-security` & `trusty-updates` and reloading and now it worked.

Can you explain by reporting the bug? Are you saying that libqt4-core should be listed as `main`, or alternatively that all its dependencies should be in `universe`? 

I posted the new output of `apt-cache policy` and it seems like it did what you said: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13480451/ it's looking for `libqt4-core` in `trusty-security/universe` and `trusty-updates/universe`.

Comment: My new sources.list has these lines `deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe` so I think that means that the `sources.list` was fixed as you were saying.

Comment: @user317258, from `apt-cache policy` output I can say it's fixed. but not from `deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe`, you should look for `deb ... trusty-updates multiverse main restricted universe` and  `deb ... trusty-security multiverse main restricted universe` not  `trusty`  which contains only the initial release: `4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4`. please, let me know if should explain more.

Comment: @user317258 , I almost forget. yes they should be all in `main` or all in `universe` . I are build from same source archive. see http://askubuntu.com/q/58364/26246 for the meaning of each component.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense, and matches what I see. Thanks!