# Cannot install/purge/upgrade after problematic upgrade

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I tried to upgrade my ubuntu version from 18 to 20.
The upgrade process was finished, but in reality my OS was not fully upgraded. I still see the old GUI and several things do not work (backup, updates, settings window do not even open).

Then i tried to `apt update` and then `apt upgrade` my packages but i am always getting errors related with unmet dependencies.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 account-plugin-tools : Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
 appmenu-qt : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8) but it is not installable
 apport : Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
 apport-gtk : Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
 aptdaemon : Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
 apturl : Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
 compiz-gnome : Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
 gedit : Depends: python3-gi (>= 3.0) but it is not going to be installed
 gnome-terminal : Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
 hplip : Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
 ibus : Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
 language-selector-gnome : Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
 libdbusmenu-qt2 : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1) but it is not installable
 libnss-systemd : Depends: systemd (= 237-3ubuntu10.57)
 libpam-systemd : Depends: systemd (= 237-3ubuntu10.57)
 libqt4-declarative : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1) but it is not installable
 libqt4-designer : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1) but it is not installable
 libqt4-help : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1) but it is not installable
 libqt4-network : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1) but it is not installable
 libqt4-script : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1) but it is not installable
 libqt4-scripttools : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1) but it is not installable
 libqt4-sql : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1) but it is not installable
 libqt4-sql-sqlite : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1) but it is not installable
 libqt4-svg : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1) but it is not installable
 libqt4-test : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1) but it is not installable
 libqt4-xml : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1) but it is not installable
 libqt4-xmlpatterns : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1) but it is not installable
 libqtassistantclient4 : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.1) but it is not installable
 libqtdbus4 : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1) but it is not installable
 libqtgui4 : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1) but it is not installable
 libreoffice-common : Breaks: libreoffice-style-galaxy (>= 1:6.1~) but 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 is to be installed
                      Breaks: libreoffice-style-tango (>= 1:6.1~) but 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 is to be installed
 libsmbclient : Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.29) but 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.7 is to be installed
 meld : Depends: python3-gi (>= 3.14) but it is not going to be installed
 networkd-dispatcher : Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
 onboard : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is to be installed
 orca : Depends: python3-gi (>= 3.18) but it is not going to be installed
 pyqt4-dev-tools : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0-1~) but it is not installable
 python-qt4 : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0-1~) but it is not installable
 python-qt4-dbus : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0-1~) but it is not installable
 python-samba : Depends: python-tdb but it is not installable
                Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.29) but 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.7 is to be installed
 python3 : PreDepends: python3-minimal (= 3.6.7-1~18.04) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
           Depends: libpython3-stdlib (= 3.6.7-1~18.04) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
 python3-all : Depends: python3 (= 3.8.2-0ubuntu2) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is to be installed
 python3-all-dev : Depends: python3 (= 3.8.2-0ubuntu2) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is to be installed
 python3-aptdaemon : Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
 python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets : Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
 python3-cairo : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is to be installed
 python3-click-package : Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
 python3-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5 : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is to be installed
 python3-dev : Depends: python3 (= 3.8.2-0ubuntu2) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is to be installed
 python3-distutils : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.8.2-0~)
 python3-gi-cairo : Depends: python3-gi (= 3.26.1-2ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 python3-lib2to3 : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.8.2-0~)
 python3-oneconf : Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
 python3-pyatspi : Depends: python3-gi (>= 2.90.1) but it is not going to be installed
 python3-pyqt4 : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0-1~) but it is not installable
 python3-pyqt5 : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is to be installed
 python3-pyqt5.qtmultimedia : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is to be installed
 python3-pyqt5.qtopengl : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is to be installed
 python3-pyqt5.qtsvg : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is to be installed
 python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is to be installed
 python3-renderpm : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is to be installed
 python3-reportlab-accel : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is to be installed
 python3-sip : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is to be installed
 python3-software-properties : Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
 python3-systemd : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is to be installed
 qdbus : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1) but it is not installable
 qt-at-spi : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8~) but it is not installable
 rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar : Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
 rhythmbox-plugins : Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
 samba : Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.29) but 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.7 is to be installed
 samba-common-bin : Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.29) but 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.7 is to be installed
 samba-dsdb-modules : Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.29) but 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.7 is to be installed
                      Depends: libwbclient0 (= 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.29) but 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.7 is to be installed
 samba-libs : Depends: libldb2 (>= 2:2.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: python3-ldb (>= 2:2.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: python3-talloc (>= 2.3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
 samba-vfs-modules : Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.29) but 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.7 is to be installed
 smbclient : Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.29) but 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.7 is to be installed
 software-center-aptdaemon-plugins : Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
 software-properties-common : Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
 software-properties-gtk : Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
 system-config-printer : Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
 system-config-printer-common : Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
 system-image-common : Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
 systemd : Depends: libsystemd0 (= 245.4-4ubuntu3.22) but 237-3ubuntu10.57 is to be installed
 totem-plugins : Depends: python3-gi (>= 2.90.3) but it is not going to be installed
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk : Depends: python3-gi (>= 3.8) but it is not going to be installed
 ubuntu-system-service : Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
 unattended-upgrades : Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
 unity : Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
 unity-scope-calculator : Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
 unity-scope-chromiumbookmarks : Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
 unity-scope-colourlovers : Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
 unity-scope-devhelp : Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
 unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks : Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
 unity-scope-manpages : Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
 unity-scope-openclipart : Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
 unity-scope-texdoc : Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
 unity-scope-tomboy : Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
 unity-scope-virtualbox : Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
 unity-scope-yelp : Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
 unity-scope-zotero : Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
 update-manager : Depends: python3-gi (>= 3.8) but it is not going to be installed
 usb-creator-gtk : Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
 xdiagnose : Depends: python3-gi (>= 3.2.0-3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I also tried what it suggests: `sudo apt --fix-broken install` but gives me again the same error.

Also followed other solutions:
[Enable the "universe" component in updates](https://askubuntu.com/a/701554/456190)
[Use Aptitude](https://askubuntu.com/a/1056378/456190),
Purging packages,

```
sudo apt configure -a
```

No matter what i tried i always end up with the unmet dependencies message

Comment: What process did you use for the upgrade?

Comment: "*I tried to upgrade my ubuntu version from 18 to 20. The upgrade process was finished, but in reality my OS was not upgraded.*" All this, and your output, suggest that your release-upgrade **failed**. You have two choices: You can 1) Laboriously troubleshoot and fix the reason for failure, or 2) You can back up your data and quickly reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: You can fresh install Ubuntu 22.04, and you the live USB to back up important files in your existing home folder

Comment: @OrganicMarble sudo do-release-upgrade
Btw. my os version is 20.04

Comment: I note numerous Qt4 messages in your paste; Qt4 was *deprecated* back in 2012 upstream (Qt project), but only finally dropped from Debian & Ubuntu repositories in 2019, thus doesn't exist in 20.04. Apps using Qt thus had 5 years to *port* to newer Qt5; [late 2019 was the cutoff or *drop*](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/removing-qt-4-from-ubuntu-before-the-20-04-release/12295).