# What is the format of the Ubuntu sources.list file?

Tags: apt, software-sources

What is the format of the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file for Ubuntu?

As an example of the kind of information I am looking for, [here](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList) is an explanation for Debian `sources.list`. However, the various sections, such as *Distribution* and *Component*, reference Debian releases; I am looking for Ubuntu specific information.

Comment: Format is the same, but distro names are different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format is exactly the same for Ubuntu.

You can get the Ubuntu distribution release names [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases). In `sources.list` use only the lowercased adjective part (precise, trusty, wily, etc.). Example:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
```

The components can be **main**, **restricted**, **universe** and **multiverse**.

More info: [What's the difference between multiverse, universe, restricted and main?](https://askubuntu.com/q/58364/65926)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the release name used in the Distribution section.  Is it acceptable to include more than one component (main, restricted, universe and multiverse) on the same line, or should you create a new line for each component you want to use?

Comment: @PJSingh You can include them all on the same line: `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse`. It works with a lot of servers that I manage (and desktops that I use), but I couldn't find any documentation that sets a limit on the number of components per line.

Answer (score 13):

To more specifically answer the question about the format of `sources.list`, I suggest `man 5 sources.list`, which you can also view on the web as [sources.list(5)](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man5/sources.list.5.html) <sup>[[alt link](https://manpages.debian.org/man/sources.list.5)]</sup>, which is more detailed than [Debian's SourcesList wiki article](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList).

My specific inquiry related to how to specify multiple options, which is covered by [sources.list(5) § The deb and deb-src types: options](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man5/sources.list.5.html#the%20deb%20and%20deb-src%20types:%20options), which says they should be space-delimited, e.g.

```
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/some-repo.gpg] http://some.repo/apt dev main
```

This becomes more relevant with the [recent apt-key deprecation](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/01/apt-key-is-deprecated-how-to-add.html) that suggests using `signed-by` for all third-party repositories. This is coming soon: "apt-key(8) will last be available in Debian 11 [released 2021.08] and Ubuntu 22.04."

(The only Ubuntu-specific part should be the release and component names, which you can learn from the prior answer to this question.)