# My Opera can't play videos

Tags: video, video-player, opera

I am using Opera 68.0.3618.125 on latest Ubuntu version. But I can't watch videos. For example on Twitter. Everyone says get libffmpeg.so and copy to `/snap/opera/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera` but I can't access this file even I'm in root access. Please help me.

Comment: Try `sudo apt install ffmpeg`, which may install the missing shared libraries.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/777573/opera-will-not-play-twitter-videos-and-others/1372009#1372009

Answer (score 4):

Install `ffmpeg`, which will install the missing shared library `libffmpeg.so`:

```
sudo apt install ffmpeg
```

Sorry for this late answer, I had only just realised my suggestion which I was not 100% certain about worked for you. But here it is.

Answer (score 3):

In my case ffmpeg didn't worked. I simply search for any possible libffmpeg.so in my system and found some varieties and pick one among them.

I selected from skype directory, and copied to opera directory and voila!! it worked!

**Below are the steps.**

- Update files DB, so it search files better.

  ```
  $ sudo updatedb
  ```
- Serach for libffmpeg.so file.

  ```
  $ locate libffmpeg.so
  /home/ravi/sw/Postman/app/libffmpeg.so
  /snap/flock-chat/281/libffmpeg.so
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/libffmpeg.so <-- This was already there. I just replaced it with skype's libffmpeg.so
  /usr/share/code/libffmpeg.so
  /usr/share/skypeforlinux/libffmpeg.so
  ```
- Backup existing libffmpeg.so, just in-case things go wrong we can revert this file.

  ```
  $ sudo cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/libffmpeg.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/libffmpeg.so.bkp
  ```
- Overwrite libffmpeg.so

  ```
  $ sudo cp /usr/share/skypeforlinux/libffmpeg.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/libffmpeg.so
  ```

Answer (score 2):

All problems with streams and Opera comes from `.deb` installation pack. We all have got `.deb` from the official Opera download page.

But official Opera has some problems with licences and official `.deb` Opera cant use latest codecs for playing streams.

**Stream works only on snap opera, not .deb**

If you have Ubuntu 20.04 u can just use this command

```
sudo snap install opera
```

Enjoy.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was struggled with this issue from years. Installing opera from snap is much faster and clear than chromium codecs and making symlink to libffmpeg

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem, just installing ffmpeg didnt work, so my solution is to copy the up to date chromium library to the opera directory. I called it `fixopera.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install chromium && mv /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/libffmpeg.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/libffmpeg.so.old && cp /usr/lib/chromium/libffmpeg.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/
```

copied it in `/etc/cron.daily/`, to make it a root cron job and executable with `chmod +x`. so in case anything goes wrong you have a backup of your old file named `libffmpeg.so.old`

Comment: Clever! :) a few questions: are you using 20.04? Did you install with snap, or apt, or any other? Thanks.

Comment: Linux Mint 20.04 (so: yes). I used the officially recommended deb package from opera website, which i think also sets an apt key so opera will be updated along with the other apps on `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade`. Btw maybe setting a cron job on `/etc/cron.daily/` is not the best way, maybe just add the script in your root crontab with `sudo crontab -e`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of replacing the existing `libffmpeg.so` (which might be undone by an update) I would suggest to create sub-directory `lib_extra` in the opera main directory and copy or symlink the *new* `libffmpeg.so` to this directory, e.g. (as root)

```
cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera
mkdir lib_extra
cd lib_extra
ln -s /path_to_other/libffmpeg.so .
```

Edit 2024-02-24: This solution does not work anymore, at least not on my Debian 12 with Opera 107.0.5045.36. Here I have to replace the file `libffmpeg.so` in the Opera directory by another file (either link or copy) as mentioned in the posts above.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the other answers, *except using a symlink instead of copying the library*, is this solution from the Opera forums, [Solving the problem of the Opera browser with video playback in Ubuntu and similar distributions (Linux Mint, KDE neon)](https://forums.opera.com/topic/37539/solving-the-problem-of-the-opera-browser-with-video-playback-in-ubuntu-and-similar-distributions-linux-mint-kde-neon):

> First of all, you need to install the `chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra`
> package. You can do this using the terminal with the following
> command:
>
> `sudo apt install chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra`
>
> Usually the second step is to create a symlink for the file
> `libffmpeg.so`, but since now the Opera browser delivers a file with
> this name (but not solving the problem), we will delete it and then
> create a simlink to the new file. File deletion:
>
> `sudo rm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/libffmpeg.so`
>
> Creating a simlink:
>
> `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/chromium-browser/libffmpeg.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/`

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's all about the libffmpeg.so file. I had to download it from a previous version of Ubuntu as explained in this post [The Videos Don't Play Topic](https://forums.opera.com/topic/42185/the-videos-don-t-play-topic/6) as none of the files in 20.04 worked.

> I did some research and replaced libffmpeg.so with the one I downloaded from https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/amd64/chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra/download

Find and extract libffmpeg.so in the downloaded package, then save it as `libffmpeg.so` in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera` (the path may vary), replacing the existing file if it is there. You will need to do this with root privileges.