# Is Chromium not exploitable via "Oxide" vulnerabilities?

Tags: google-chrome, security, chromium

[Ubuntu security notices](https://www.ubuntu.com/usn/) lists Oxide vulnerabilities very frequently.
I counted 7 of them in 14.04.

[They usually look like this.](https://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3113-1/) Chromium is mentioned as the originator of the vulnerability, but it's not listed in the title, and no Chromium upgrades are suggested.

Why is that? Is Chromium not exploitable through the same vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, Ubuntu Security Notices are for software in `main` or `restricted` ([What's the difference between multiverse, universe, restricted and main?](https://askubuntu.com/q/58364/158442)). Only software in `main` and `restricted` are supported by Canonical, and hence, only they get USNs. Oxide is in `main`, but [Chromium the browser is in `universe`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=chromium).