# Can't install gtfp using terminal in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-installation

I tried to install gftp ftp client but when i type command `sudo apt-get install gftp` terminal response me:

> E: Unable to locate package gftp

Comment: Make sure you have [enabled the universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) then run `sudo apt-get update` and try again

Comment: Thank you so much it works, but i want to ask what does universe repository do ?

Comment: It's the repository that contains the package that you are trying to install - see [What's the difference between multiverse, universe, restricted and main?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58364/whats-the-difference-between-multiverse-universe-restricted-and-main)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add *universe* repository manually, update lists and install `gftp`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gftp
```