# Will it be safe to use python 2.7 on Ubuntu 18.04 after python 2 EOL?

Tags: python, security, python-2.7

Ubuntu 18.04 will still be supported after 2020, yet python 2.7 will reach its end of life. If a CVE or a bug raises for python 2.7 after 2020, will the Ubuntu package get an official fix (through APT)? Will there be any risk incurred by using python 2.7 after 2020 on an Ubuntu machine? Should we expect the maintainers to be less reactive? Will there be a warning somewhere in the interpreter on in the logs?

Comment: "unsupported" does not mean it stops working.

Comment: I have never said it would stop working, but if CVE would get patched.

Answer (score 4):

Python 2.7 is still in `main` for 18.04 (and [is the last LTS release to include it in `main`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes#Other_base_system_changes_since_16.04_LTS)). There is [ongoing effort to have it moved to `universe`](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-announce/2017-December/001234.html), but that wasn't completed before 18.04 released. Thus, the same commitment that Canonical applies to other software in `main` (like the kernel, which has been maintained past upstream support, for example) will hold for Python. [What's the difference between multiverse, universe, restricted and main?](https://askubuntu.com/q/58364/158442)