# How to install dos2unix on a Ubuntu app on a Windows-10 machine

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, windows-10

I have a Ubuntu app, installed on my Windows-10 machine. As far as versions are concerned, this is the result of `uname -a`:

```
Linux <username> 4.4.0-17134-Microsoft #523-Microsoft Mon Dec 31 17:49:00 PST 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Using this Linux "emulator", as I call it, I regularly do `grep`, `find`, `wc -l`, `sort`, ..., for analysis purposes, but this sometimes generates output files in UNIX format (I'm talking about line endings).

In order to get Windows line endings, I decided to launch a `unix2dos` on the file, but this gave following error message:

```
The program 'unix2dos' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install dos2unix
```

In other words, my app knows that, in order to do `unix2dos`, the package `dos2unix` is needed. This looks like good news, except for the fact that I'm not able to install it:

```
sudo apt install dos2unix
[sudo] password for <username>:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package dos2unix
```

I have already installed packages before, so it should be a problem specific for the `dos2unix` package.

For your information:

- I don't have a `/var/log/messages` file.
- `dmesg` doesn't work: `dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Function not implemented`
- I have a `/var/log` directory, but the latest file/directory modification is around a week ago.
- I have a `/var/log/apt` directory, but the latest file/directory modification is around a week ago.
- I tried debugging this myself, using `strace`, but this failed (`strace: exec: Operation not permitted`, `+++ exited with 1 +++`).

**Edited after first comment**

```
apt-cache policy
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-security,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-security,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-updates,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-updates,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
Pinned packages:
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Please add the output of `apt-cache policy` to your question. It shows the packages sources you are using.

Comment: @FlorianDiesch: I edited my question accordingly (I have no knowledge about `apt-cache policy`, I have no idea what this means.

Comment: Can you `sudo add-apt-repository universe` and then `sudo apt update && sudo apt install dos2unix`

Comment: @CharlesGreen: thanks: the `get-repository universe` was obsolete, but the two second ones solved my situation. Please add it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: it ad add-repository... but I'm glad it worked for you.  Basically @FlorianDiesch and I were going in exactly the same direction, and he was here 1st!  Please note that the `apt` commands usually com in two parts `apt update` my list of software and `apt upgrade` the software in my system.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This solved my problem:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dos2unix
```

Comment: Worked on Raspbian too

Answer (score 3):

You need to ativate the "universe" repository component. See [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) for how to do that.

See [What's the difference between multiverse, universe, restricted and main?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58364/whats-the-difference-between-multiverse-universe-restricted-and-main) for more information about repository components.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that it will help but my Eclipse build template command started working after I noticed the last line of text above the prompt after running the command "sudo apt update" in the Ubuntu command shell, the first of 4 command lines found in the "Intel FPGA Software Installation and Licensing" guide section 2.3.1.  The text referred to items that needed to be "Upgraded"  The command "sudo apt upgrade" worked for me.  I then re-ran the remaining three command lines and looked for anything else that needed to be upgraded.  There were none.  After that I was suddenly able to create Eclipse project templates, but I had tried everything else I could find before that point and the process woudl fail with the error message failed to execute dos2unix.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: How is this answer any different and how is it better or more concise than the [top, accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1179725)? https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer | https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting | https://askubuntu.com/tour