# Install older package version (from bionic) in ubuntu eoan

Tags: apt, package-management

I must use "scons" in version 3.0.x but in Ubuntu eoan scons is at version 3.1.x [0]. I tried to edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and added

```
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main
```

After `sudo apt update` `sudo apt list scons` still only shows `scons/eoan,eoan 3.1.1.-3 all`

How can I install scons 3.0.x on Ubuntu Eoan?

[0] https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=scons

Comment: Did you try installing `scons` with the version name as well?  `sudo apt install scons=3.0.1-1`  After you install that version it is recommended that you put a hold on the app so it doesn't upgrade `sudo apt hold scons` then remove or comment out the older bionic source.

Comment: `sudo apt install scons=3.0.1-1` results in `Version '3.0.1-1' for scons was not found`

Comment: Ah, you setup the wrong PPA.  It is in the `universe` and not `main`.  After setting it up you should be able to run `apt-cache madison scons` and it should show you all the versions available.

Comment: thank you, it works! What does `universe` and `main` stand for?

Comment: Here's the best info I can give you for that:  https://askubuntu.com/a/58365/231142

Comment: Thank you. By the way `sudo apt hold scons` doesn't work but `sudo apt-mark hold scons` does

Comment: Oops, my bad!  That is what I get for writing a response this early in the morning!  =)  Glad it is working for you!