# Ubuntu support if GUI is changed

Tags: ubuntu-mate

I have a question which derived from a comment I got to another question. I know that LTS Ubuntu versions have support for 5 years so that means that Ubuntu 16.04 is supported up to 04/20.

If I replace the GUI of Ubuntu with another not supported version like mate (which I have done) without formatting is this considered an action that breaks the system and, thus, it is now considered Ubuntu mate instead of Ubuntu or not?

Comment: This applies for any package: only `main` is officially supported (and maybe `restricted`, but canonical depends on the original maintainers here), `mate-desktop` is in `universe`. If you install `universe`/`multiverse` packages it does not affect the support status of packages from `main`. [See also](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58364/whats-the-difference-between-multiverse-universe-restricted-and-main).