# How to use software-properties-gtk --enable-component=ENABLE_COMPONENT?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, software-center, gtk

I would like to enable or disable certain options in the application `software-properties-gtk` via command-line.

Examples of the options that I am interested to control via command-line are shown below:

[image: a]
[image: b]

I suspect the command `software-properties-gtk --enable-component=ENABLE_COMPONENT` would allow me to implement what I want. However, [manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/software-properties-gtk.1.html) does not elaborate what values can be used to replace `ENABLE_COMPONENT`.

```
$ software-properties-gtk -h
Usage: software-properties-gtk [options]

Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -d, --debug           Print some debug information to the command line
  -m, --massive-debug   Print a lot of debug information to the command line
  -n, --no-update       No update on repository change (useful if called from
                        an external program).
  -t TOPLEVEL, --toplevel=TOPLEVEL
                        Set x-window-id of the toplevel parent for the dialog
                        (useful for embedding)
  -e ENABLE_COMPONENT, --enable-component=ENABLE_COMPONENT
                        Enable the specified component of the distro's
                        repositories
  --open-tab=OPEN_TAB   Open specific tab number on startup
  --enable-ppa=ENABLE_PPA
                        Enable PPA with the given name
  -k KEYSERVER, --keyserver=KEYSERVER
                        Legacy option, unused
  --data-dir=DATA_DIR   Use data files (UI) from the given directory
```

Appreciate instruction on using this command?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/58365/158442

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS I see the following:

> ```
> $ software-properties-gtk --enable-component=main
> The --enable-component/-e command-line switch has been 
> deprecated. Instead of 'software-properties-gtk -e multiverse' 
> you can use 'add-apt-repository multiverse'
> ```

So really you have to use

```
add-apt-repository component
```

where component is one of [the following](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#What_are_Repositories.3F):

> - `main` - Canonical-supported free and open-source software.
> - `universe` - Community-maintained free and open-source software.
> - `restricted` - Proprietary drivers for devices.
> - `multiverse` - Software restricted by copyright or legal issues.

So the full commands would be

- `sudo add-apt-repository main`
- `sudo add-apt-repository universe`
- `sudo add-apt-repository restricted`
- `sudo add-apt-repository multiverse`

For Canonical Partners you can use the command shown below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) partner"
```

where `lsb_release -cs` will return the *codename* (bionic, focal, hirsute, etc) of your Ubuntu version.

---

Stuff to read:

- `man sources.list` locally or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/sources.list.5.html);
- `man add-apt-repository` locally or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/add-apt-repository.1.html).

Comment: Thanks. I just came to the same findings as you in 20.04. And to disable a component I should use `sudo add-apt-repository -r main` as an example. There is one other part that I have found a solution to yet and your answer has not mentioned. That is, how to enable/disable `Canonical Partners` in the `Other Software` Tab. Can you elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: For partners you can use `sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) partner"`  .