# Why are some packages made by Canonical in the universe?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, repository, canonical

If I understand correctly, the `main` repository is for open-source packages made by Canonical and supported by Canonical and the `universe` repository is for open-source software made by the Ubuntu community. I found this driver

https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/rtl8812au-dkms

that's in the `universe`, but in the changelog ([https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/universe/r/rtl8812au/rtl8812au_4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg-0ubuntu13~20.04.3/changelog](https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/universe/r/rtl8812au/rtl8812au_4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg-0ubuntu13%7E20.04.3/changelog)) 
it's created and updated by Canonical employees (e.g. Tim Gardner, Ricardo Salveti de Araujo).

Why is it then in the `universe` and not in the `main` repository?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between multiverse, universe, restricted and main?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58364/whats-the-difference-between-multiverse-universe-restricted-and-main) See also: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Comment: The Changelog entries show that the package is being occasionally rebuilt and patched by Canonical engineers. Inclusion in `main` is a commitment that they will continue doing so in the future. Inclusion in `universe` means they they are being nice and neighborly and had the resources available, but not a commitment for future work.

Comment: Many packages touched/created by Canonical staff are found in 'universe' as they are part of the community too. For LTS releases there are *more expensive* requirements in placing packages in 'main', so finding them in 'universe' highlights they don't come with a 5 year support guarantee (that applies to 'main' only) with 'universe' packages having a shorter life (the norm is 3 years for anything *flavor* related anyway); though the option is still there for the wider community to step in and fix things after *flavor* support drops after 3 years).

Comment: Not a duplicate: "duplicates" do not expand on why a Canonical package could be in universe.