# I get this message when trying to install the .NET SDK or the .NET Runtime on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-sdk

```
abdoalmowafy@DESKTOP-R32B14O:~$ sudo apt-get update && \
o apt-ge>   sudo apt-get install -y dotnet6
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package dotnet6
```

[the screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Uhxl.png)

I get this message when I try to install dotnet on my pc
It says "E:" and I don't have any hard disk partition called "E"
I had it once but I merged it with another partition
Is there any relation ?

Answer (score 2):

The organization of hard disks and other storage media in Ubuntu (and Linux in general) is quite different than it's done in Windows. There are no drives denoted with letters like `C`, `D`, `E` and so forth. The `E` in your error message simply stands for "**E**rror". There are also "**W**arnings", denoted by `W`, and so forth.

The error in your case is that you try to install a package called `dotnet6`, but `apt-get` can't find a package by this name. You may need to activate the repository or component that contains this package.

Packages are organized in components. Among the main components are "Main", "Universe", "Multiverse" and "Restricted". The [main differences between those components](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58364/whats-the-difference-between-multiverse-universe-restricted-and-main) are how the software in the packages is licensed and whether Canonical (the company behind Ubuntu) provides support for the packages or not.

As you can see from the [description of the package `dotnet6`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/dotnet6), this package is located in "universe". So you need to check whether you have activated the "universe" component. This can be done with a graphical interface from the "Software" tool, see for example [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Ubuntu_Software_Tab).

Or you can edit the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` (with root privileges). There, look for a line similar to

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main universe restricted multiverse
```

and check that "universe" is included. Maybe you'll find the components on individual lines like

```
...    
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
...
```

EDIT: I just realized that you're using an older release of Ubuntu, 20.04 Focal. The package `dotnet6` isn't included in this release, it's only available since 22.04 Jammy. You either need to upgrade your installation to at least 22.04, or to get the package `dotnet6` from another source.