# Ubuntu 22.04 Skipping acquire of configured file can not find error

Tags: apt, updates, 22.04

Ok I have seen others with this skip error but I still can not locate where it is on my system. I do not see the misspelling and can not find a jammy inRelease anywhere.

W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease

Below is my current sources.list file

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu jammy partner universe
```

grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ shows

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualmin.list:deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/debian-virtualmin-7.gpg] https://software.virtualmin.com/vm/7/gpl/apt virtualmin main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu   jammy stable
```

Comment: `grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` Please [edit] your question to show us.

Comment: I updated this. Still can not figure it out.

Comment: me too. `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` and try again. If not working `dpkg --print-architecture` and `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` please.

Comment: dpkg --print-architecture
amd64

Comment: dpkg --print-foreign-architectures returned nothing

Comment: Ran sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* and Still gettign same 2 messages after update

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I am blind. The formating in not correct. universe and multiverse are not part from main unlike restricted. Please change it too

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
```

More info please take a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58364/whats-the-difference-between-multiverse-universe-restricted-and-main) I'm really bad in explaining in english.