# Skipping acquire of configured file multiverse/restricted/universe in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: package-management, 22.04, software-sources

I am trying to install `rar` and `unrar` on an Ubuntu 22.04 system, which I believe are in multiverse (following some instructions that said to add all of multiverse, restricted, and universe).

I ran `add-apt-repository multiverse`, `add-apt-repository restricted`, and `add-apt-repository universe`, but after doing so and attempting to run `apt update -y`, I get the following warnings:

```
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
```

I have looked at similar questions, but all that I have found deal with prior Ubuntu releases or other repositories, and I'm not sure what my `sources.list` is supposed to look like after adding those repositories.

My `sources.list` file is:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy universe multiverse restricted main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates universe multiverse restricted main
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu jammy multiverse partner restricted universe
```

I tried adding `[arch=amd64]` after `deb` on each line, but this made no difference.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: @Terrance country code *isn't* a requisite.  `archive.ubuntu.com` does work.  OP's problem is they have the Partner repositories set and trying to pull pockets that don't exist in it.

Comment: @ThomasWard Ah, you are right.  Use it for faster access to the repos.  =)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the file has the wrong formatting.

The answer by user `nobody` here worked. https://askubuntu.com/a/1460166/1095763

In case it gets deleted, `sources.list` needs to be:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
```

Comment: The formatting in the question is perfectly fine, your actual problem is that `universe`/`multiverse`/`restricted` don't apply to the `http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu` repository

Comment: In the other answer, you also need to make sure that you state the part that `universe`/`multiverse` cannot work with `main` like `restricted` can.